# Autocomplete gem for a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm looking for suggestions on autocomplete gems for a rails app. I'll be searching for users and would like it to display a list underneath (similar to facebook). Any suggestions?

Comment: [Autocomplete on Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, rails has a gem for this called `rails4-autocomplete`. Here is the link

https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete

This helps for JQuery's autocomplete.

Comment: That's what I'm most likely going to go with. Any resources for installation tutorials? I'm using the readme as we speak but if there's a video of someone walking through it that would be very helpful!

Comment: According to the docs, just put `gem rails4-autocomplete` in the gemfile and then run `bundle`. You also have to add `//= require autocomplete-rails` in application.js. Videos might be on railscasts.

Comment: I guess I mean implementing more than I meant installing. Sorry for the incorrect verbage